# If $X_i$ are i.i.d. and $Y_i$ are i.i.d, are $Z_i$ = $X_iY_i$ i.i.d?

Tags: random-variable, independence

Clearly $X_iY_i$ have the same distribution, but are they independent, given that there can be a dependent relationship between the $X_i$ and the $Y_i$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The $Z_i$ are not necessarily independent. For example, suppose $Y_i = X_{i-1}$. Then $Z_i = X_i X_{i-1}$ and $Z_{i+1} = X_{i+1} X_i$ both depend on $X_i$

Comment: I don't think this by itself answers the question. Consider sequence of constant functions. They are independent and your argument fails. The answer to the question should be of the lines "not necesserally, here is a counter example" because it clearly can be true, but it is not always true.